# Find position of another anchor than the anchor already used

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a code to show my problem. It looks like this:

```
userNameID = tkinter.Label(root, text="Name/ID")
userNameID.place(x=640, y=320, anchor="e")

userNameID = tkinter.Label(root, text="Password")
userNameID.place(x=640, y=360, anchor="e")

entButton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Enter", command=enterPrint)
entButton.place(x=640, y=400, anchor="w")
```

The thing is that I have aligned some text on one size of the center and a button on the other side. I want to know the position of the northwest anchor for the texts to make sure everything is the same distance away from the center and still aligned.

Comment: If you're just now learning tkinter, I _strongly_ encourage you to learn `grid` or `pack` instead of `place`. You're making a lot of extra work for yourself.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I unfortunately find them to "imprecise". With the endless grid I can not get it to make sense. The pack function doesn't seem to have any parameters to me but i might have misunderstood something. Thank you though, a lot of your answers on this site has really helped me out

Comment: `grid()` and `pack()` are very precises. You just don't know yet how to implement what you want. There are many examples for your problem here and on the net.

Comment: Actually, I would argue grid and pack are not precise, and that's the point. You place widgets relative to each other, and tkinter does all the math for you. You shouldn't care that a label ends at 100px and the entry starts at 120, you should only care that the label is to the left and the entry is to the right. `place` is certainly a little easier to learn for the most basic of layouts, but it quickly becomes a quagmire if you need the UI to be responsive.

Comment: @BryanOakley I guess my wording can use some work. `grid()` and `pack()` are far easier and quicker to set up and change. Knowing how to use each makes things as precises I have have ever needed but I should probably not say they are more precises.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: once you learn them, yes, they are easier to set up and change, no question about that.  If you are just getting started, however, there's a bit of a learning curve. While both are quite powerful, and both are dead simple to use, they can be hard for some people to wrap their head around. With `place`, however, everyone can grok `x=100,y=200` with absolutely no learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grid()` and `pack()` are "precises" enough for most needs. You just need to learn how to properly use these geometry managers to their fullest. In fact the use of `place()` is almost never what you need. It has its case uses but it is not a great choice for general GUI setups. It is also very hard to manage for updating your code.

Update: To answer you question in the comments:

> Row configure means that you put every row to be 1 pixel because of the weight? I know I can draw a grid over the whole thing but I don't know how many rows, columns my program has. therefore I can't find the center.

The weights are used to tell a specific row or column should resize at a certain ratio in relation to the other rows and columns around them within the same grid/container. The default weight is zero. When we set the weight to 1 then that row or column will resize with the window at an even rate.

Take this example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

center_frame = tk.Frame(root)
center_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

tk.Label(center_frame, text='Name/ID').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(center_frame, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(center_frame, text='Enter').grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]    [image]

In the above example you will see that the widgets do not move when you resize the window. This is because we have not instructed tkinter to allow any rows or columns to move.

If we add this weight to the program `root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`:

Then we get this affect:

[image]

Next add this `root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)`:

[image]

Next add this `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`:

[image]

Next add this `root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)`:

[image]

As you can see with the above images depending on what rows and columns you have set a weight to then the rows and columns will resize accordingly. What we achieve with the above code is to have rows 0 and 2 resize and columns 0 and 2 resize. `row 1 column 1` will not resize. So that means anything we place in the `row 1 column 1` position will not resize but rather maintain its relative location to the borders. Because we set a frame widget in the `row 1 column 1` position and then all of our widgets inside the frame we have effectively made `row 1 column 1` the center.

There are as many rows and columns as you tell it to have. Tkinter will automatically adjust the total rows and columns based on what you say. Adding to that it will also make rows and columns with nothing in them a zero size. That means only rows and columns with content(widgets) will actually affect the size of the grid.

Say we have 3 rows and 3 columns. Depending on how we fill it it will change the size of whats being displayed.

In this example anywhere you see an `X` shows we put something in the following rows and columns.

In this example we have something in (0,0), (1,1) and (2,2).

```
                ROW
         0       1       2
     *-------*-------*-------*
     |       |       |       |
   0 |   X   |       |       |
C    |       |       |       |
O    *-------*-------*-------*
L    |       |       |       |
U  1 |       |   X   |       |
M    |       |       |       |
N    *-------*-------*-------*
     |       |       |       |
   2 |       |       |   X   |
     |       |       |       |
     *-------*-------*-------*
```

In this example we have something in (0,0) and (2,2).

```
         0       2
     *-------*-------*
     |       |       |
   0 |   X   |       |
     |       |       |
     *-------*-------*
     |       |       |
   2 |       |   X   |
     |       |       |
     *-------*-------*
```

In this example we have something in (1,0), (2,1) and (2,2).

```
         0       1       2
     *-------*-------*-------*
     |       |       |       |
   1 |   X   |       |       |
     |       |       |       |
     *-------*-------*-------*
     |       |       |       |
   2 |       |   X   |   X   |
     |       |       |       |
     *-------*-------*-------*
```

The above examples illustrate what is automatically shown depending on what row and grid you fill with widgets.

As for the arguments like `sticky` these are used to manages behavior of each widget. For example if we tell a widget to fill all the space in a given row/column then we would use `sticky='nsew'`. If we want a widget to stretch in a given row/column horizontally but not vertically we would use `sticky='ew'` for east/west. Keep in mind the sticky argument is for `grid()`. The `pack()` geometry manager has it own arguments.

There are many options and you can find a list of them here with their descriptions:

[For `grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

[For `pack()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Take the below example. This code will set up the labels and button cent of the window at all times even when you resize the window. This is far easier to manage than place.

There are many useful arguments you can use in your geometry managers to achieve just about any behavior or alignment you wish. Just take the time to dig into it. I know `place()` feels like the best option (I thought the same when I first started before Bryan corrected that notion :D) but it really is not.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

center_frame = tk.Frame(root)
center_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

tk.Label(center_frame, text='Name/ID').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(center_frame, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(center_frame, text='Enter').grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example using `pack()`. I find `grid()` to be my go to but `pack()` can be used to accomplish much as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

center_frame = tk.Frame(root)
center_frame.pack(expand=True)

tk.Label(center_frame, text='Name/ID').pack(side='top')
tk.Label(center_frame, text='Password').pack(side='top')
tk.Button(center_frame, text='Enter').pack(side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "(`place()`) has its case uses"... what are good examples of its use cases? Because it is true that "`place()` is almost never what you need".

Comment: @ReblochonMasque adding an image directly to a button and setting a background image on an application that is not affected by the resizing of the GUI are 2 I can think of off the top of my head. That said in the year I have been programming I have only had use for place exactly one time so far.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: any time you need to place a widget with an absolute position or relative to another widget, and which doesn't affect or isn't affected by other widgets. For example, adding an image as a background of a frame or toplevel. Creating a little grip for resizing things. Tooltips are another potential use. It can be useful for creating an MDI (multiple document interface, where you have multiple independently movable windows inside another window). There aren't many general purpose uses, but several special purpose uses.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen (@Mike-SMT, @BryanOakley), your responses are very helpful.

Comment: I just need to understand this 100%. Row configure means that you put every row to be 1 pixel because of the weight? I just don't understand the grid. I know I can draw a grid over the whole thing but I don't know how many rows, columns my program has. therefore I can't find the center

Comment: How come all 3 rows still move when it is only row=0 you have configured. I don't understand the part where you say the frame automatically is at the center. Why wouldn't you put the frame at 0,0 guess that is the top corner of the window? Sorry for the many questions

Comment: @SnitchingAuggie the reason all the widgets move together is because they are only on 1 row and column inside of a frame. This frame was placed on the row1 column1 position of the root window that was not configured for a weight. This leaves that frame to stay only big enough for the widgets and that row/column gets to move because the surrounding rows have weight and are growing or shrinking with the window.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand everything perfectly well now

Comment: _"The weights are used to tell tkinter that a specific row or column should resize at a certain ration with the window. "_ is slightly incorrect. The weight has nothing to do with the row or column relative to the window, it has to do with the row or column relative to other rows and columns in the same grid.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks. I have updated my wording to be more accurate.