# Python Tkinter Grid System

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program in Tkinter and I want to use .grid but when i do .grid(row = 2, column = 4, rowspan and other things in grid) those doesn't work...
here's the code:

```
def play():
w_quiz = Tk()
w_quiz.title("QUIZ")
w_quiz.geometry("300x500+400+100")
w_quiz.resizable(False, False)
w_quiz.configure(bd = 20)
sv_anw = StringVar(value="")
e_anw = Entry(w_quiz, textvariable = sv_anw)
e_anw.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? How is it not working. Judging by the code you provided this will not work as you have bad indention and no `mainloop()`.

Comment: Assuming you mean that when you set a row and column the widget appears to only show up in position 0/0 then this is because tkinter only shows rows and columns that have something in them and shrinks the rest. This is a fairly common problem and has been asked several times here.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749781/find-position-of-another-anchor-than-the-anchor-already-used/50750928#50750928). I explain in more detail how the grid manager works.

Comment: @Mike-SMT ok thank you, sorry for disturbing

Comment: They are working as documented. empty rows and columns have a size of zero.