# Why does my button not go to the far right of my GUI window?

Tags: python, tkinter

The `column` value on my button is set to 500, but the button doesn't seem to move that far to the right.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

logo = Label(root,text = "New File Finder")
new_folder = Button(text = "browse new folder")
old_folder = Button(text = "browse old folder")

logo.grid(row=0, column=8)
new_folder.grid(row=1,column=1)
old_folder.grid(row=1,column=500)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Empty columns have a width of 0 (by default), so it does not matter how many you put in. Use `pack(side=RIGHT)` to place things on the right side.

Comment: @Novel: be careful with your terminology. It won't put it to the right side of the window, it will put it to the right side of any available space, which could very well not be the right edge of the window.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750928/7475225). I go into detail on the behavior of the grid manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Novel mentions, empty columns have a width of 0, so your `column=8` has the same effect as `column=2`, and `column=500` as `column=3`. And of course your column 0 has a width of zero. You could use `.pack` instead of `.grid`, as Novel suggests, but don't mix `.pack` and `.grid` into the same container widget, which is the root window in this case. However, you can achieve what you want via the `.grid` `sticky` arg, but you also need to set a column weight for the column containing the `old_folder` Button. Eg:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

logo = tk.Label(root, text="New File Finder")
new_folder = tk.Button(root, text="browse new folder")
old_folder = tk.Button(root, text="browse old folder")

logo.grid(row=0, column=1)
new_folder.grid(row=1,column=0)
old_folder.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

I also changed the "star" import, since that dumps 130 Tkinter names into your namespace, which is messy, a waste of space, and can cause name collisions, especially if you do other star imports.

---

As Bryan mentions, `.pack(side=RIGHT)` doesn't actually force the widget to the right side of the container, it merely tells `.pack` to pack the widget towards that side. So if you pack a bunch of widgets with `.pack(side=RIGHT)` they'll be packed from right to left instead of from the default top to bottom. You can control exactly where inside the widget's allotted space that you want the widget to be placed using the `anchor` arg. Also take a look at the various `pad` args. See [the Pack docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack-method) for details.