# Tkinter aligning text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to align screen text. I have been unsuccessful in properly aligning the text I want to display. Currently this is displaying on a 24" monitor and I cannot get some of the text to go all the way to the right of the screen. I have tried

```
sticky=E
```

but it did not move the text to right.[Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bgq5.jpg)

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

win = Tk()

###################################################################################################
##################################### CONFIGURATIONS ##############################################
###################################################################################################


#Change according to the true target value for this shift
TARGET_VALUE = 600

#Change according to the target value displayed for this shift
TARGET_DISPLAY = 480

#Change to met you display sizes , try by increasing and decreasing this value to change labels
SIZE = 120


###################################################################################################
########################################### END ###################################################
###################################################################################################


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

ACTUAL_VALUE = IntVar()
ACTUAL_VALUE.set(0)

ACTUAL_CTR=0

Efficiency_VALUE = IntVar()
Efficiency_VALUE.set(100)

StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
currentState  = 0
previousState = 0

myFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = SIZE , weight = 'bold')
win.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
BACKGROUND = 'white'
win.configure(background=BACKGROUND)

def getNumberOfMinutes(a,b):
        c=b-a
        x=divmod(c.days*86400 + c.seconds,60)
        return x[0]

def RESET():
    global StartTime
    global Efficiency_VALUE
    global ACTUAL_VALUE
    global BACKGROUND
    global ACTUAL_CTR

    print(" Reset pressed")
    ACTUAL_VALUE.set(0)
    ACTUAL_CTR=0
    Efficiency_VALUE.set(100)
    StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    BACKGROUND = 'white'
    win.configure(background=BACKGROUND)

def task():
    global StartTime
    global TARGET_VALUE
    global ACTUAL_CTR
    global BACKGROUND
    global Efficiency_VALUE
    global previousState
    global currentState
    Eff_Value = 0

    if(ACTUAL_CTR != TARGET_VALUE):
            TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now() 

            currentState = GPIO.input(40)

            if (currentState == 1 and previousState == 0):
                    ACTUAL_CTR=ACTUAL_CTR+1
                    ACTUAL_CTR = int(ACTUAL_CTR)
                    ACTUAL_VALUE.set(ACTUAL_CTR)

            previousState = currentState
            Minutes= getNumberOfMinutes(StartTime,TimeNow)
            if(Minutes < 1):
                    Minutes=1
            if(ACTUAL_CTR >0):
                            Eff_Value = ((ACTUAL_CTR/Minutes)/(TARGET_VALUE/48000))
                            if(Eff_Value>135):
                                    Eff_Value=135
                            Eff_Value = int(Eff_Value)
            Efficiency_VALUE.set(Eff_Value)
            if(Eff_Value >= 80):
                    BACKGROUND = 'green'
            elif(Eff_Value >= 70):
                    BACKGROUND = 'yellow'
            elif(Eff_Value < 60):
                    BACKGROUND = 'red'

            win.configure(background=BACKGROUND)
            win.after(500,task)
    else:
            print "finished"


Label(win,text="%",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=2,column=30)
Label(win,text="PCS",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=2,column=80)
Label(win,text="",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=3,sticky=W)

Label(win,text="Target:",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=4)
Label(win,text="75",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=4,column=30)
Label(win,text=TARGET_DISPLAY,font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=4,column=80)
Label(win,text="",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=5,sticky=W)

Label(win,text="Actual:",font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=6)
Label(win,textvariable=ACTUAL_VALUE,font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=6,column=80)
Label(win,textvariable=Efficiency_VALUE,font=myFont,bg=BACKGROUND).grid(row=6,column=30)

win.after(500,task)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to see if you're giving any weights to rows or columns, and how `win` is put in its parent.

Comment: I have a detailed answer about how the geometry manager works for `grid()`. This will explain why you are not able to simple use columns to move your widget to the right of the screen. Here: [Details on grid manager resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750928/7475225)

Comment: This is way too much code. Please try to narrow it down. And since this is purely related to the visual experience, the example shouldn’t depend on `matplotlib` and `RPi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set a weight for the center column. Weights are used to tell the column/row to expand a specific rate.

Add this line just under `win = Tk()`:

```
win.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Then change your columns in your labels to the following.

```
Label(win,text="%").grid(row=2,column=1)
Label(win,text="PCS").grid(row=2,column=2)
Label(win,text="").grid(row=3,sticky=W)

Label(win,text="Target:").grid(row=4)
Label(win,text="75").grid(row=4,column=1)
Label(win,text=TARGET_DISPLAY).grid(row=4,column=2)
Label(win,text="").grid(row=5,sticky=W)

Label(win,text="Actual:").grid(row=6)
Label(win,textvariable=ACTUAL_VALUE).grid(row=6,column=2)
Label(win,textvariable=Efficiency_VALUE).grid(row=6,column=1)
```

This should move all your labels on the far right that are meant to be there and then the mid labels to the cent of the screen.