# How do i place a frame in the bottom right corner of my window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im pretty new to programming in python and using tkinter. i want to make a widget, and place it in the bottom right corner of my window, but im unsure of how to place a frame there.

ive made the window fullsscreen and currently have two widgets in the top left corner using grid. Ive spent quite some time trying to find a solution, but most things dont really work as i want them too, or i dont understand whats happening too well

Comment: Here is a link to one of my post describing the behavior of the grid manager. It should help you understand exactly what is going on when setting up a grid of widgets. [Grid Manager Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750928/7475225)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly, it's possible to use `grid` to make a widget remain at the lower-right corner of the window.

- First, use `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to inform the window which rows and columns should stretch when the window is larger than the total width/height of all grid elements. Assuming you want the other elements of your window to stay where they are, you should weight the column and row your frame resides in.
- Second, use the `sticky` argument in `grid` to inform the frame which edge of the grid it should adhere to when the grid is larger than the frame.

Example:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

a = tkinter.Button(root, text="Reticulate")
b = tkinter.Button(root, text="Frobnicate")

a.grid(row=0, column=0)
b.grid(row=0, column=1)

f = tkinter.Frame(root)
f.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tkinter.SE)

g = tkinter.Button(f, text="quit")
g.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]