# How do I get my frame sizes to match up to my root window size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a text game. I used an entry widget for player input, a text widget for the game's output, and put them into frames. I set the root window's geometry and the frame sizes to fit into that geometry. However, the frame sizes are smaller than expected. Specifically, my `story_text_frame` is shorter than expected. I have done a tutorial, and am not sure what I am missing now.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.geometry('1280x720')

        self.player_input_frame = tk.Frame(self, height=20, width=625)
        self.player_input_field = tk.Entry(self.player_input_frame, background='black', foreground='white', relief='flat')
        self.player_input_field.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.player_input_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.story_text_frame = tk.Frame(self, height=670, width=625)
        self.story_text_field = tk.Text(self.story_text_frame, background='grey', foreground='white')
        self.story_text_field.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.story_text_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

To have a widget size follow the size of a master widget or a window you must specify how this is to be done with `columnconfigure()` and `rowconfigure()`. Then you must expand the widget to fill the available cell space by instructing `grid()` to stick to the edges; `sticky='nsew'`. See my example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.geometry('800x600')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Specify how columns and rows will 
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     # change when window size changes.

        # The game's output Text() widget
        self.story_text_field = tk.Text(self)
        self.story_text_field.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew',
            pady=10, padx=10)  # Sticky expands the widget to fill the cell

        # The player input Entry() widget
        self.player_input_field = tk.Entry(self)
        self.player_input_field.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(0,10))

Game().mainloop()
```

I have removed the Frames to make the construction clearer. Also I removed the coloring of the widgets. I introduced some padding to make the result more pleasing to the eye and changed the window size to be easier to handle on my tiny screen.

For further information on `grid()` I can recommend effbot's [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). You can also read Mike - SMT's answer to [Find position of another anchor than the anchor already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749781/find-position-of-another-anchor-than-the-anchor-already-used/50750928#50750928) which elaborates on both `grid()` and `pack()`.