# Row and Column of GUI controls not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to create a simple GUI application. My code is below. The row and column seems to have no affect. Column 0 is showing up at the center of the screen. If I make Row as 1, the control still appears at Row 0.

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Sample App")
window.geometry('640x480')

tkinter.Label(window, width="5", text="Title").grid(row="0", column="0")
```

**Edited**

Identified the issue. The original code is in Visual Studio. I copied the same on Spyder and the coordinates are working fine.

What could be the issue with VS 2019?

Comment: When I run your code the label appears in the upper-left corner, which is where I would expect it. Are you sure _this exact code_ produces a label at the center of the screen?

Comment: But in my case, even if row/column are 4/5, it appears at the center of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find position of another anchor than the anchor already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749781/find-position-of-another-anchor-than-the-anchor-already-used)

Comment: I give a break down of how the geometry manager is working on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750928/7475225) with visual aid.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Please check comment in the answer below. It is IDE configuration issue.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks for that link. It has detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell, `tkinter` will set your lowest row/column to 0 and use it as a reference point. You would need another widget for comparison, but in my testing the two examples to follow yield the same exact GUI.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Sample App")
window.geometry('640x480')
tkinter.Label(window, width="5", text="Title").grid(row=0, column=0)
tkinter.Label(window, width="5", text="Title1").grid(row=1, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

And

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Sample App")
window.geometry('640x480')
tkinter.Label(window, width="5", text="Title").grid(row=5, column=5) # or even 50000, 50000
tkinter.Label(window, width="5", text="Title1").grid(row=6, column=6) # and 50001, 50001

window.mainloop()
```

I bet the answer to why this behavior is seen would be explained if you dove into `.grid()` source code. To answer your question though, the controls **are** working, but with only one widget it will always grid it at the top left of the screen at (0, 0) even if you specify (100000, 100000) because of this behaviour of defining the origin as the minimum row/column specified. You would need a widget at (0, 0) **and** a widget at (100000, 100000) for that to work as far as I'm aware!

Comment: It's not so much related to an origin or reference point, it's simply that empty rows and columns have a width and height of zero. If you have one widget at (0,0) and one at (100000,100000) they will appear very close to each other.

Comment: @Reedinationer I identified the issue. The above code I wrote in Visual Studio. It seems to be not working there. But now I copied on Spyder and row columns are working.Wondering what could be the issue in VS.

Comment: @RKh... oh Visual Studio for python code. Didnt know it did anything outside of dot net. I like PyCharm for my python coding.

Comment: @Mike-SMT VS added Python support and now VS Code is also there.