# How change the number of columns Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a program with Tkinter, It have 6 entry labels. 
I'm with difficulty to grid these labels in the center of page.
I don't wanna to use .pack

How can I set the number of columns that the grid has? It seems tkinter ignore when I set column=6 for example.

here my code:

```
               ##Input 1 / Input de parametros
            self.PwNomeLabel1 = Label(text = "Cliente:")
            self.PwNomeLabel1["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel1.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest1 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest1["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest1.grid(row=0, column=3)
            ##Input 2
            self.PwNomeLabel2 = Label(text = "Responsavel por Teste:")
            self.PwNomeLabel2["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest2 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest2["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest2.grid(row=1, column=3)
            ##Input 3
            self.PwNomeLabel3 = Label(text = "Nome do Sistema:")
            self.PwNomeLabel3["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel3.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest3 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest3["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest3.grid(row=2,column=3)
            ##Input 4
            self.PwNomeLabel4 = Label(text = "Ref:")
            self.PwNomeLabel4["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel4.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest4 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest4["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest4.grid(row=3,column=3)
            ##Input 5
            self.PwNomeLabel5 = Label(text = "Data Base:")
            self.PwNomeLabel5["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel5.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest5 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest5["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest5.grid(row=4,column=3)
            ##Input 6
            self.PwNomeLabel6 = Label(text = "Data Teste:")
            self.PwNomeLabel6["font"] = ("10")
            self.PwNomeLabel6.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=W)
            self.inputpwtest6 = Entry(borderwidth= 2, validate='key')
            self.inputpwtest6["width"] = 30
            self.inputpwtest6.grid(row=5,column=3)

            root = Tk()
            root.title("TEST PLATFORM")
            Application(root)
            root.geometry('1366x768')
            root.mainloop()
```

In this way its results:

[image]

If I change label columns to "4" and "5" for the entry results:

[image]

Like the prints, It seems the Tkinter get confused and the grid stay desorganized

Comment: Tkinter auto collapses rows/columns that are empty. You can do several things to adjust your code to get the effects you want though. The used of `sticky` and `columnconfigure()` are probably what you want. That said your question is not clear enough to provide a solid answer. What exactly is your goal? Do you want everything to be centered? Do you want things to be spaced out? What is the issue specifically?

Comment: I would like to set the column freely, like the printscreen, when I put column = 5 its deconfigures totally. I would just to set the label column where I want for.

Comment: What do you mean *"like printscreen"*? There is normally a way to get things to look the way you want with grid(). When you say you want to set the column freely that is not strictly possible. At least not with grid(). For a static placement of widgets you can use `place()` however I think `grid()` is still the correct choice you just need to learn how grid works. Here is a post I wrote to explain how grid works. [Grid Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750928/7475225)

Comment: Print screen that I posted, (images), I read this post and I think this may help me, I'll try some configures now

Comment: Do you want the Labels to be in the center?

Comment: Yes, by setting the column number. When I set the last label it deconfigures all the others and back 1 column back

Comment: Ah I see. You can provide spacing in a few ways. Column weights, or padding, or a empty label.

Comment: Yeah, It was a problem with Row/Column weight, Thanks @Mike-SMT through the post that you have mentioned, now I got what I wanted.

Comment: @LucasCruz I have added a answer related to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are likely needing to manage row/column weights.

Here is an example that does that while also showing how you can reduce your code by dynamically generating labels and entry fields instead of writing a wall of text for all of them.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')
root.title("TEST PLATFORM")
label_list = ['Cliente:', 'Responsavel por Teste:', 'Nome do Sistema:', 'Ref:', 'Data Base:', 'Data Teste:']
entry_list = []

# Row and Column configure to manage weights
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

# Add a frame to hold the rest of the widgets and place that frame in the row/column without a weight.
# This will allow us to center everything that we place in the frame.
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

# use a loop to create our widgets.
for ndex, label in enumerate(label_list):
    tk.Label(frame, text=label, font='10').grid(row=ndex, column=0, sticky='w')
    # Store the entry widgets in a list for later use
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(frame, borderwidth=2, width=30))
    entry_list[-1].grid(row=ndex, column=1)

# Get and print each entry value.
def print_entries():
    for entry in entry_list:
        print(entry.get())


tk.Button(frame, text='Selecionar Arquivo', command=print_entries).grid(row=len(label_list)+1, column=0, columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I never could that were possible to create widget in this way (a loop), but for my application I can't use this method, because I'll need to store the entries in a variable to assign it value to cells in excel using openpyxl. Otherwhise this method is totally  usefull for an another application that I have. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasCruz I do not see how needing to send the values to an excel sheet changes anything. You simply loop through the list of entries and append the values to the excel sheet. I do it all the time. In fact I finished an application recently for my work that does this.

Answer (score 0):

If a column is empty (no widget inside), then it will not appear.

In the following example, I put a frame in column 0 with `width=100` in order to have my column 1 "centered". I also have the parameter `weight=1` for the 3 columns, so it grows the same way when I expand the window.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(3):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

tk.Frame(root, width=100).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
# tk.Label(root, text='Left').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
tk.Label(root, text='Center').grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text='Right').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried but doesn't worked for any reason, my window got all blank and the labels disappear